# grails with gorm for rest and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rest, grails, client, grails-orm

Just started a grails 2.5.5 app with gorm-rest-client and followed the guide, but I get the following error when starting the app

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restclientTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restclientTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restclientDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restclientDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restclientMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restclientMappingContext': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'pluginManager' of bean class [org.grails.datastore.gorm.rest.client.plugin.support.RestClientMappingContextFactoryBean]: Bean property 'pluginManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

this only happens when I have the hibernate plugin installed, if I remove the hibernate plugin, it works perfectly.

The intent of this is to have a mix of some Domain Classes mapped with Rest and some others with Hibernate so I can use them together with Gorm, i.e.:

```
RestDomain {
    static hasMany = [notRestDomains: NotRestDomain]
}
RestDomain.list().each { println it.notRestDomains.size() }
```

is it possible? or am I just wishing too much?